# IBM-MQ reader in .net XMS to ack processed messages one-by-one

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am implementing a component that reads all the messages off a specific queue as they are available but should only remove messages from the queue asynchronously, after the message contents has been processed and persisted. We read messages off faster than we acknowledge them (e.g. we could read have read 10 messages off before we are ready to Ack the first). The current implementation uses the XMS API, but we can switch to MQI if XMS is inappropriate for these purposes.

We have tried two approaches to try solve this problem, but both have drawbacks that make them unacceptable. I was hoping that someone could suggest a better way.

The first implementation uses an `IMessageConsumer` in a dedicated thread to read all messages and publish their content as they are available. When the message has been processed, the `message.Acknowledge()` method is called. The Session is created with `AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge`. The problem with this approach is that, as per the documentation, this acknowledges (and deletes) ALL unacknowledged messages that have been received. With the example above, that would mean that all 10 read messages would be acked with the first call. So this does not really solve the problem. Because of the reading throughput we need, we cannot really modify this solution to wait for the first message's ack before reading the second, etc.

The second implementation uses an `IQueueBrowser` in a decided thread to read all messages and publish their content. This does not delete the messages off the queue as it reads. A separate dedicated thread then waits (on a BlockingQueue) for JMS Message IDs of messages that have been processed. For each of these, it then constructs a dedicated `IMessageConsumer` (using a message selector with JMSMessageID) to read off the message and ack it. (This pairing of an `IQueueBrowser` with dedicated `IMessageConsumer` is recommend by the XMS documentation's section on **Queue browsers**.) This method does work as expected but, as one would imagine, it is too CPU-intensive on the MQ Server.

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior, messages can't be acknowledged random. One message acknowledge will ack all earlier messages. There is no option in MQ .NET either. From  your description it appears that you are OK with acknowledging all messages with one ack call but you more concerned about throughput. What throughput are you expecting?

Comment: Expected throughput: Up to 1 million messages per day on the most active queue and 10 million messages per day for all queues on the MQ server combined.

Comment: Just to clarify: the main reason that we can't really read and process each message sequentially (before reading off the next) is that the actual processing has a fairly significant lead time - that's why we need to have many messages being processed simultaneously.

Comment: Both of your proposed methods appear to rely on a single instance of the app.  What's wrong with using multiple app instances, transacted sessions and COMMIT? The performance reports all show that throughput is maximized with multiple app instances and horizontal scaling is one of the most used approaches in your scenario.

Comment: @T.Rob how would you structure it? Multiple threads each with their own Session and Consumer; each reading one message and then waiting for it to be processed?
Also: would you make your comment into an Answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the methods proposed in the question appear to rely on a single instance of the app. What's wrong with using multiple app instances, transacted sessions and COMMIT? The performance reports (these are the [SupportPacs](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) with names like MP**) all show that throughput is maximized with multiple app instances, and horizontal scaling is one of the most used approaches in your scenario.

The design for this would be either multiple application instances or multiple threads within the same application.  The key to making it work correctly is to keep in mind that transactions are scoped to a connection handle.  The implication is that a multi-threaded app must dispatch a separate thread for each connection instance and the messages are read in the same thread.

The process flow is that, using a transacted session, the app performs a normal `MQGet` against the queue, processes the message contents as required and then issues an `MQCommit`.  (I'll use the MQ native API names in my examples because this isn't language dependent.)  If this is an XA transaction the app would call `MQBegin` to start the transaction but for single-phase commit the transaction is assumed.  In both cases, `MQCommit` ends the transaction which removes the messages from the queue.  While messages are under syncpoint, no other app instance can retrieve them; MQ just delivers the next available message.  If a transaction is rolled back, the next `MQGet` from any thread retrieves it, assuming FIFO delivery.

There are some samples in:
`[WMQ install home]\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\xms\simple\wmq\`
...and `SimpleXAConsumer.cs` is one example that shows the XA version of this.  The non-XA version is simpler since you don't need the external coordinator, the `MQBegin` verbs and so forth. If you start with one of these, make sure that they do not specify exclusive use of the queue and you can fire up several instances using the same configuration.  Alternatively, take the portion of the sample that includes creation of the connection, message handling, connection close and destroy, and wrap all that in a thread spawner class.

[*Insert usual advice about using the latest version of the classes here.*]

Comment: So I have since tried this out and it worked as described. But I do have one follow-up question: I suppose there is no easy way in this setup to skip a particular message (in the case where my application is unable to process a message) and leave it on the queue for another application or a future run?

Comment: The accepted pattern for that is to employ a rework queue or exception queue.  The IBM JMS classes will look for the queue attributes `BOQNAME` and `BOQTHRESH`.  Once the rollback count on the message exceeds `BOQTHRESH`, the message will automatically be requeued to the `BOQNAME` queue.  This requires no additional program logic, just define the queue, set `BOQTHRESH` and point `BOQNAME` at the exception queue.  Some apps follow a similar pattern but add their own logic to handle the requeue which is a more portable approach.  Then just work the exception queue as appropriate.